# Документация по PyWin32

Tags: python, pywin32

Нигде. ВООБЩЕ нигде не могу найти нормальной документации по PyWin32. Где можно найти нормальную документацию, список методов (если будет описание методов - вообще круто). Я нашел только этот нечитабельный сайт : [Этот](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyWin32.html). Как им пользоваться - не ясно.